# Python Request GET with Client Certificate is failing

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I'm trying to send an HTTP GET request using Python Requests to an API that is requiring a Client Certificate.  I'm passing in a PEM and Key file into the GET request using

```
session = requests.Session()
session.get('https://localhost/rest/containers/7uyeogzKQayw4mmQmcJb2Q/listeners', cert=('development.pem', 'development.key'))
```

When making this call, I'm using NGINX as the endpoint, I'm getting:

```
2017-10-07 21:18:16,874 - containerLogger - DEBUG - code:400   text:
<html>
<head><title>400 No required SSL certificate was sent</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>No required SSL certificate was sent</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.12.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tested the same API using a POST request against the same endpoint using the same certificates and it is successful.  I've validated the same GET using a browser (Firefox) successfully.

I'm currently trying to figure out why the POST is successful, but the GET is failing. I'm not having any luck in searching for an answer.

Not sure if this is due to requests or urllib3.

Versions:

- Java 1.8
- Jython 2.7.1
- Python 2.7.10
- Requests 2.18.1
- urllib3
- certifi 2017.04.17

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers - Erik

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating a `session = requests.Session()` the documentation requests that you have `session.cert = '/path/to/client-cert.crt'`

An easier way is to pass it as a tuple.

```
requests.get('https://localhost/rest/containers/7uyeogzKQayw4mmQmcJb2Q/listeners', cert=('/path/client.cert', '/path/client.key'))
```

Documentation Link

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say.  I already add the cert as a tuple on the call to the get.  I tried to even change to using a requests over session and it still fails.  Using session.cert is just a persistent way of setting the cert, based on the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled upon the same issue.
Here is my solution:

```
response = requests.get(url, cert=(curr_cert, curr_key), verify=False)
print response.content
```

You were missing the **trusted cert**. Requests verifies SSL certificates for HTTPS requests, just like a web browser. By default, SSL verification is enabled, and Requests will throw a SSLError if it’s unable to verify the certificate (Just like in your case)

**verify=False** should resolve the issue

By setting verify=False, you will get warnings like the following:

*InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings*

If you do want to verify ssl verification, the following should help:

```
response = requests.get(url, cert=(curr_cert, curr_key), verify=verify='/path/to/trustedcertfile')
print response.content
```